# How do you apply a restart policy on gitlab-ci services?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a `Gitlab-CI` job with multiple services needed to run integration tests :

```yaml
variables:
  FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 'true' # Create a network for all services of a build

my-test-job:
  services:
    - name: myservice-a:1.0.0
      alias: serva

    - name: myservice-b:1.0.0
      alias: servb
```

The service B needs the service A to be up and running to work. If service A is not available when service B starts, the service B crashes.

On `Kubernetes` or `docker-compose` it's not a problem because of built-in retry mechanism. With `Gitlab-CI` services there is no retry mechanism [according to the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/), so I'm wondering how I can avoid race conditions issues in this case ?
Moreover, I can't use `docker-compose` on `Gitlab-CI`, because I need to use shared runners from my company without root access.

I could probably use a [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) solution but I would prefer not to modify the images if possible.

Comment: Isn't running a `docker-compose` in your `gitlab-ci` a better solution?

Comment: I can't use docker-compose because I need to use shared runners from my company without root access, so no dind, no docker-compose unfortunately. I will add this to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the entrypoint of the services like this:

```html
  services:
    - name: service
      entrypoint:
        - '/bin/sh'
        - '-c'
        - |
          echo 'some waiting script'
          echo 'call real entrypoint here'
```

Then you can use a 'wait-for-it' logic and afterwards start the real entrypoint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's hard to believe there is not better solution that this, how are we suppose to run integration tests if retry mechanism is not implemented ?

Comment: @XavierFRANCOIS With the possibility to write your custom entrypoint you can implement a restart routine yourself. For example by starting your service (not as a daemon) in a while loop, so when it stops because of failure it restarts again.

Comment: Finally that's what I did, I use a wait-for-it script without modifiying the service image. It's not ideal but as it stands there is no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The restart policy for services is not user-configurable.

Besides making your own entrypoint as [Kerrim suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75733897/5747944) (see also: [additional reference](https://zanechua.com/blog/dependency-between-services-gitlab-pipelines)), if you can't configure service B to use retries in its startup logic, you should just avoid using `services:` for this use case altogether and orchestrate your testing within the `script:` section entirely.

For example, if you have an approach using `docker-compose` that works, consider just invoking `docker-compose` in your job `script:`.

Comment: I can't use docker-compose because I need to use shared runners from my company without root access, so no dind, no docker-compose unfortunately